# Android, org.simpleframework.xml Persistence Exception, Element 'foo' is already used

Tags: java, android, xml, simple-framework

I am using the org.simpleframework.xml to handle some xml tasks for an android application and am running into the following error which I cannot figure out.

```
org.simpleframework.xml.core.PersistenceException: Element 'album' is already used with @org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList(inline=false, name=album, entry=, data=false, empty=true, required=true, type=void) on field 'albums' private java.util.List us.blah.sonar.xsd.simple.AlbumList.albums at line 5
at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Variable$Adapter.read(Variable.java:484)
at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readVariable(Composite.java:613)
at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readInstance(Composite.java:573)
```

Here is a sample of the XML I'm trying to unmarshall:

```
<albumList> 
    <album id="3985" parent="3301" title="Bob Dylan - The Reissue Series Sampler" album="Bob Dylan - The Reissue Series Sampler" artist="48 - Masked and Anonymous [BSO] (2003)" isDir="true" created="2011-12-09T11:52:12"/> 
    <album id="3986" parent="3301" title="Soundtrack - Masked & Anonymous" album="Soundtrack - Masked & Anonymous" artist="48 - Masked and Anonymous [BSO] (2003)" isDir="true" coverArt="3986" created="2011-12-09T11:52:13"/> 
    <album id="10542" parent="145" title="A Perfect Circle" album="Acoustica" artist="A Perfect Circle" isDir="true" created="2011-12-09T12:01:52"/> 
</albumList>
```

And here are the **POJOs** I created and annotated:

```
@Root
public class AlbumList {

    @ElementList(name="album")
    private List<Child> albums;

    public List<Child> getAlbums() {
        return albums;
    }

}

public class Child {
    @Attribute
    private String id;

    @Attribute(required=false)
    private String parent;

    @Attribute
    private boolean isDir;

    @Attribute
    private String title;

    @Attribute(required=false)
    private String album;

    @Attribute(required=false)
    private String artist;

    @Attribute(required=false)
    private int track;

    @Attribute(required=false)
    private int year;

    @Attribute(required=false)
    private String genre;

    @Attribute(required=false)
    private String coverArt;

    @Attribute(required=false)
    private long size;

    @Attribute(required=false)
    private String contentType;

    @Attribute(required=false)
    private String suffix;

    @Attribute(required=false)
    private String transcodedContentType;

    @Attribute(required=false)
    private String transcodedSuffix;

    @Attribute(required=false)
    private int duration;

    @Attribute(required=false)
    private int bitRate;

    @Attribute(required=false)
    private String path;

    @Attribute(required=false)
    private boolean isVideo;

    @Attribute(required=false)
    private String userRating;

    @Attribute(required=false)
    private double averageRating;

    @Attribute(required=false)
    private int discNumber;

    @Attribute(required=false)
    private Date created;

    @Attribute(required=false)
    private Date starred;

    @Attribute(required=false)
    private String albumId;

    @Attribute(required=false)
    private String artistId;

    @Attribute(required=false)
    private MediaType type;
}
```

Can anyone lead me in the right direction on how I can fix the issue, or what exactly this error message means? Is it because the XML element is named album and there is an attribute also named album?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try to annotate your `AlbumList` class this way:

```
@Root
public class AlbumList {
    @ElementList(entry="album", inline=true)
    private List<Child> albums;

    public List<Child> getAlbums() {
        return albums;
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you very much. I'm not sure why that works though. I didn't think the album elements were inline since they are wrapped with the albumList tags.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem you may [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) it.

Comment: I wish that the default was inline=true... I just hit this problem. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: Any chance what I should do if it's not a list? For example, if the backend is incorrect and has two nodes with the same name, how do I avoid this persistenceexception?

Comment: @McAdam331 you should post a new question for that.