# SimpleXML: Element 'link' is already used

Tags: java, android, xml, deserialization, simple-framework

Hello and sorry for my bad English.
Look at the XML I'm trying to parse:

```
<author>
<name>Name</name>
<y:link href="http://api-yaru.yandex.ru/person/20623655/" rel="self"/>
<y:link href="http://upics.yandex.net/20623655/normal" rel="userpic"/>
</author>
```

And SimpleXML code looks like:

```
public class Author_feed {
@Element
private String name;

@ElementList(inline = true)
@Namespace (prefix = "y")
private List<Link_feed> link;
}
```

Hovewer I see an error:

> Element 'link' is already used...[and points to the second  "link" line]

What shall I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found this link [Android, org.simpleframework.xml Persistence Exception, Element 'foo' is already used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474368/android-org-simpleframework-xml-persistence-exception-element-foo-is-already)

try using `@ElementList(entry="link", inline=true)`

Another reference that might be helpful is [Annotation Type ElementList](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/ElementList.html)

Comment: Thanks! But I've got another (similar) problem. May I somehow contact you? Just one question.

Comment: try this chat room .. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33794/room-for-paolo-casciello-and-kneel-before-zod